# Importing a function from another file, where to import other libraries?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Simple question, I've searched to no avail. Say I have a file "funcs.py", in it there's a function I want to call into my current script. The function uses another library (e.g. pandas), where do I import that library? What's the convention?

Do I put it inside the function in funcs.py?

```
#funcs.py
def make_df():
    import pandas as pd
    return pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2,3],data=[1,2,3])
```

Do I put it *outside* the function in funcs.py?

```
#funcs.py
import pandas as pd

def make_df():
    return pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2,3],data=[1,2,3])
```

Or do I put it in the current script I'm using?

```
#main.py
import pandas as pd

from funcs import make_df

df = make_df()
```

Thanks and kind regards.

Comment: Convention says import statements go at the top of the file. So the first example with import inside the function should *not* be used. But the last two examples look correct.

Comment: The import statement should be in the file where it has been used. So it should be in funcs.py preferably outside the function so if you need to use the same package in another function within same file you need not to import again. Hope it helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python each file is a *module*. Each module has its own *namespace* - its own set of variables. Each function also has its own local namespace.

When you use the name `pd` in a function defined in the module `func`, it will first look for the local variable `pd` in the function - if it doesn't exist,
it will look for it in the namespace of its module, `func`. It will *not* look for it in the module `main`, even if the code calling the function is in main.py

This is known as lexical scoping - the rule is that variables are looked up close to where the code is *defined*, not where it is *used*. Some languages do look up variables close to where the code is used, it's known as dynamic scoping- in one of these languages something like your solution #3 would work, but most languages including Python follow lexical scoping rules, so it won't work.

So pandas has to be imported in funcs.py. main.py doesn't have to import or even
know anything about pandas to use `make_df`.

If you import pandas at the top of func.py, then when you import the module `func` from main.py, the line `import pandas as pd` at the top of func.py will be executed, the pandas module will be loaded, and a reference to it will be created in `func` bound to the name `pd`. There is no need to re-import it in main.py.

If you do re-import pandas in main.py, Python will be smart enough not to reload the entire module just because you imported it in two places, it will just give you a reference to the already loaded pandas module.

Putting the import in the body of the function will work but it's not considered good practice, unless you have a really good reason to do so. Normally imports go at the top of the file where they are used.

Answer (score 2):

#3 wouldn't work. In most cases, #2 is the preferred option (the main exception would be if the library is a large (slow to import) library that's only used by that function). You might also want to consider one of these options (for optional dependencies):

```
#funcs.py
try:
    import pandas as pd
except ImportError:
    pass

def make_df():
    return pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2,3],data=[1,2,3])
```

or

```
#funcs.py
try:
    import pandas as pd
except ImportError:
    pass

if pd is not None:
    def make_df():
        return pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2,3],data=[1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the source at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?#imports

> Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module
>   comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants.

Best practice is to do all imports on the first few lines of your script file, before doing any other coding

Comment: The link does not help much as it shows the best practices of importing according to Pep8 rules. OP's question is two folds where to import and how to import

Comment: You're right, I added the relevant quote from the documentation, hopefully that's clearer

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to include at the beginning of your code in `funcs.py`

There is no need and you should not include `pandas` in your `main.py`.

Basically when you use `import pandas` `pandas` library becomes part of your code.

Comment: Ok coolio, cheers. I was trying consider the logic. So if you import a function from another file, it doesn't just import that function as some independent segment of code, but also any library dependencies the function uses (that were imported in its native file).

Comment: Yes. just like you are importing `func.py` (or a function from it)  in your main

Comment: "Becoming part of your code" sounds like you're using `from pandas import *`.