# pd not defined when importing custom functions locally

Tags: python, pandas, python-import

I have files with functions saved locally that I want to load.  However, when I do this, its not picking up already loaded loaded packages such as pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x=pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3]})
```

This function is saved locally to a test_function.py    file...it isn't run in my jupter notebook directly.

```
# saved on file locally...
def multiply_values(data):
    if data.__class__ == pd.DataFrame():
        return(x.iloc[:,0]*2)
```

Load the function...

```
from test_function import *
multiply_values(x)
```

I then get

```
NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

Can someone explain to me how I should be handling this?  How am I not importing this correctly?

I also updated the test_function.py file to have

`import pandas as pd` as the very first line & within the function itself.

I get this response:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-00666e9e2407> in <module>
      1 xx = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,23,234,3]})
      2 
----> 3 multiply_values(xx)

~/Downloads/testfunc.py in multiply_values(data)
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 
----> 3 
      4 def multiply_values(data):
      5     import pandas as pd

NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52526269/importing-a-function-from-another-file-where-to-import-other-libraries

Comment: Put `import pandas as pd` in `test_function.py`.  Also, `multiply_values()` outputs a TypeError in your example fyi.

Comment: @MichaelGardner thank you for the help.  I tried this and I didn't work.